# How do I find a specific number pattern within a column of strings and replace that value with a text version of that ordinal number?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, spyder

Please forgive, I am new to python. But am building a function that I can use to clean text for various surveys. I feel I am close to converting numeric version of ordinal numbers to the text version, but I'm not quite there. Here is the function I am trying to build (Note, I tried 2 ways to find the regex pattern on the *nbr = * line in the function but I get errors for both which I have explained below):

```
import pandas as pd
from num2words import num2words
import re

my_df = pd.DataFrame({"record": [47,56,59,134,454],
                      "the_string": ["this is the first string",
                                     "this is the 2nd string",
                                     "nothing to see here",
                                     "4th string has the date: today is the 8th",
                                     "this has a typo10th"]})

def replace_ordinal_numbers(words):
    nbr = re.findall('(\d+)[st|nd|rd|th]', words) #words.str.findall('(\d+)[st|nd|rd|th]')
    
    newText = words
    for n in nbr:
        ordinal_words = num2words(n, ordinal=True)
        newText = words.replace(r'\d+[st|nd|rd|th]', ordinal_words)
    return newText

my_df['the_string_clean'] = replace_ordinal_numbers(str(my_df['the_string']))
```

ERRORS:
When I run `words.str.findall` on the "nbr = " line in the function, I get the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`  And when I run the `re.findall` I am able to get a dataframe, but 'the_string_clean' column doesn't reflect the strings on each row. Instead I am getting:

```
    record  the_string                  the_string_clean
0   47      This is the first string    "0This is the first string 1This is the 2nd string 2nothing to 
                                        see here 3 4th string has the date: today is the 8th 4This has 
                                        a typo10th"
Name: the_string, dtype: object
1   56      This is the 2nd string      "0This is the first string 1This is the 2nd string 2 nothing to 
                                        see here3 4th string has the date: today is the 8th 4This has a 
                                        typo10th"
Name: the_string, dtype: object
2   59       nothing to see here        "0This is the first string 1This is the 2nd string 2 nothing to 
                                        see here3 4th string has the date: today is the 8th 4This has a 
                                        typo10th"
Name: the_string, dtype: object
3   134      4th string has the         "0This is the first string 1This is the 2nd string 2 nothing to
             date: today is the 8th     see here3 4th string has the date: today is the 8th 4This has a 
                                        typo10th"
Name: the_string, dtype: object
4   454      this has a typo10th        "0This is the first string 1This is the 2nd string 2 nothing to 
                                        see here3 4th string has the date: today is the 8th 4This has a 
                                        typo10th"
Name: the_string, dtype: object
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT: This is the output I'm expecting:

```
record    the_string                                 the_string_clean
47        this is the first string                   this is the first string
56        this is the 2nd string                     this is the second string
59        nothing to see here                        nothing to see here
134       4th string has the date: today is the 8th  fourth string has the date: today is the eighth
454       this has a typo10th                        this has a typotenth
```

I hope I am clear enough. I am new to Python and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your `replace_ordinal_numbers` function by using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20m#re.sub) and calling `num2words` in a lambda function as the replacement. Then just use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to run the function over the column:

```py
import pandas as pd
from num2words import num2words
import re

my_df = pd.DataFrame({"record": [47,56,59,134,454],
                      "the_string": ["this is the first string",
                                     "this is the 2nd string",
                                     "nothing to see here",
                                     "4th string has the date: today is the 8th",
                                     "this has a typo10th"]})

def replace_ordinal_numbers(words):
    return re.sub(r'(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th)', lambda m: num2words(m.group(1), ordinal=True), words)

my_df['the_string'] = my_df['the_string'].apply(replace_ordinal_numbers)

my_df
```

Output

```
   record                                       the_string
0      47                         this is the first string
1      56                        this is the second string
2      59                              nothing to see here
3     134  fourth string has the date: today is the eighth
4     454                             this has a typotenth
```

Note that you need to use an alternation `(?:st|nd|rd|th)` in your regex to match one of `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th`; the character class you are using: `[st|nd|rd|th]` will match any string which contains any of the characters in `dnrst|`.